# Shuffling a deck of $n$ cards

Tags: probability

Consider the following technique for shuffling a deck of $n$ cards:

> For any initial ordering of the cards, go through the deck one card at a time and at each card, flip a fair coin. If the coin comes up heads, then leave the card where it is; if the coin comes up tails, then move that card to the end of the deck. After the coin has been flipped $n$ times, say that one round has been completed.
>
> For instance, if $n = 4$ and the initial ordering is $1, 2, 3, 4$, then if the successive flips result in the outcome $h, t, t, h$, then the ordering at the end of the round is $1, 4, 2, 3$.
>
> Assuming that all possible outcomes of the sequence of $n$ coin flips are equally likely, what is the probability that the ordering after one round is the same as the initial ordering?

I am not sure how to start solving this? Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the flips is a tail then all of the following flips must be tails also, in order for the card to be able to return to its original position.

It is easy to see that each of the outcomes of this form leave the stack of cards unchanged. There are $n+1$ such outcomes (because the number of tails can range between $0$ and $n$.

Hence the probability is $\frac{n+1}{2^n}$.

Comment: There are a few more than that.  If the first $k$ flips are heads and the next $n-k$ are tails then the cards will be in their initial order.  For any $k\in\{0,..,n\}$

Comment: Right, thanks.${}$

Answer (score 0):

The point is that if you want to preserve the order of any subset of an ordered set, you cannot have H's followed by T followed by H, or T's followed by H followed by T, because those will definitely ruin the order. So the total possibilities are $k$ H's followed by $n-k$ T's for $n$ cards, where $k = 0,1,2,\cdots$.